# Somar data com valores do banco. CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, postgresql, data, cakephp-3

Preciso fazer um calculo que soma um número inteiro á uma data. Esse número inteiro se refere á dias.

```
$user = TableRegistry::get('PoliticaSenha');

$query = $user->find()->where(['id' => $usuario['politica_senha_id']])->first();

$dataTrocaUsuario = $usuario->ultima_troca_senha->format("d/m/Y");

$dataValidade = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+".$query->validade_dias ." days", strtotime($dataTrocaUsuario)));

        echo $query->validade_dias;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $dataValidade;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $dataTrocaUsuario;
```

esse é o meu resultado:

```
2 - 02/01/1970 - 22/01/2016
```

Não sei o que está errado, procurei pela internet toda e é isso que dizem para fazer para somar datas. Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: `validade_dia` de dias é o número inteiro?

Comment: isso mesmo, como pode observar no resultado do echo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o método `add()` da classe DateTime, provavlmente o cake utiliza ela por padrão para manipular datas, para ele basta passar uma instancia do periodo desejado, seja em dias, meses, anos etc.

O problema do seu código é fazer a formatação da data e depois a manipulação, as operações por padrão são feitas no formato `Y-m-d` quando você manda em outro formato uma data inválida é gerada.

```
$query = $user->find()->where(['id' => $usuario['politica_senha_id']])->first();

$dataTrocaUsuario = $usuario->ultima_troca_senha;
$dataValidade = $dataTrocaUsuario
dataTrocaUsuario->add(new DateInterval("P{$query->validade_dias}D"));

echo $query->validade_dias;
echo ' - ';
echo $dataValidade->format('d/m/Y);
echo ' - ';
echo $dataTrocaUsuario->format('d/m/Y);
```